PostgreSQL Aurora Read IO background process
We have AWS Aurora PostgreSQL with one write instance and one read instance.
Each day some background process runs. I can see on Read IO chart that it starts at 2AM UTC and last approximately for 20 hours.
Can someone help me understand what is this process? I can't see any active queries.
After I added new 50GB table that process started to consume twice more IO.
